# Why is Component not drawing anything?

Tags: java, swing, graphics

sorry, this is probably a really basic question, but i have a class thats called butterfly with the code for drawing a butterfly object like so:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.BasicStroke;

public class butterfly extends JPanel {
public butterfly() {
}
     public void draw(Graphics2D g2){
    //the width of the oval. A petal is an oval.

    //TODO: Your code goes IN HERE (not in main), ALL OF IT. Replace the code below.

    //draw one oval of length 300pixels from center to edge
    g2.setColor(Color.blue);
    g2.fillOval(500,55, 70, 70);
    g2.fillOval(450, 40, 70, 70);
    g2.fillOval(460,100, 40, 40);
    g2.fillOval(495, 110, 40, 40);


    g2.setColor(Color.black);
    g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(13));

    g2.drawLine(520, 50, 490, 150);

 }

}
```

also then i tried putting it in this component so i can put more objects with it but it won't even draw the butterfly?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class RippingOffofAmy extends JComponent
{

    private butterfly yay;

    public RippingOffofAmy()
    {
        yay = new butterfly();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

       //checks to see if rectangle has moves 100 places yet
       //if has, then adds new obstacle and resets count
       yay.draw(g2);

        //draws obstacle and avatar
    }

}
```

why? (ignore the class names and comments I used some of my friends code)If I'm missing something can someone be really specific about what to add bc I'm terrible at java, thanks!

Comment: This is not how to do Swing drawing and it looks like you're taking wild guesses at how to do this, don't.  Have you gone through the tutorials yet? That's where I'd start: [Lesson: Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)

Comment: If you're still stuck after reviewing the tutorials, then consider creating and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org) or a [minimal example program/mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) where you condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles and runs, has no outside dependencies (such as need to link to a database or images), has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem.

Comment: 1) A Butterfly doesn't need to be a Panel 2) where's the main method to show your GUI?

Comment: oh yeah thanks! and yeah I'm taking wild guesses lol I suck but thank you!!

Comment: @user2130108 Then learn. Saying you suck and not proactively trying to improve your knowledge is bad.

Comment: Post your [mcve] and let's see what's really going on. For all we know, your RippingOffofAmy class is 0 x 0 in size. Also you should be calling the super's paintComponent method in your override.

Comment: first of all what does that even mean haha and idek how to write a main method class like what would I put in it? Every time I try to look things up I get really confused

Comment: How can you know that this code isn't displaying anything if you've not yet created a main method, a JFrame, and displayed it?

Comment: I didn't know you needed a main method to display things tbh

Comment: Love you guys for the help but I'll just delete this question it's too much of a mess

Comment: `"I didn't know you needed a main method to display things"` -- unless you're creating applets, but no one creates those these days.

Comment: oh i created one! but it still doesn't do anything?

Comment: public class RealTester {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        RippingOffofAmy one = new RippingOffofAmy();
    }
}

Comment: Lord. Again, please read a tutorial, I can't beg you enough. There's nothing wrong with ignorance, and none of us were born with Java knowledge, but to perpetuate ignorance without showing effort, now that's a sin. Please delete this question and read a Swing tutorial asap. You can find links to the Swing tutorials and to other Swing resources here: [Swing Info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info)

Comment: Actually I can't delete this question but I tried and actually I got it my friend helped me out but thank you! and yeah I will I'm just in a time crunch

Answer (score -1):

You should read some tutorials, however here is what you tried to do.

Here is what i would do:

```
package de;

import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Butterfly extends JPanel {
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setColor(Color.blue);
    g2d.fillOval(500,55, 70, 70);
    g2d.fillOval(450, 40, 70, 70);
    g2d.fillOval(460,100, 40, 40);
    g2d.fillOval(495, 110, 40, 40);


    g2d.setColor(Color.black);
    g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(13));

    g2d.drawLine(520, 50, 490, 150);
}
```

}

Brief explanation:
Creat a JFrame(which is the window itself)
Override the pain function of JPanel
Input the code for the butterfly into the pain function
create a 'Butterfly'(which extends JPanel)
add the butterfly to the JFrame
run the program :)

Comment: Why no constructer? because we extend JPanel and all we would do is call super anyway, java does this for you. if you have another way of doing it, please show me, i am eager to learn more!

Comment: @user2130108: what's going on is that you should post your [mcve] and not borrow this well-meaning but misguided code.

Comment: honestly guys thanks but its ok  I don't think I know anywhere near enough to even ask a question and Im sorry for wasting your time but thanks for trying to help!

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels oh yeah, i forgot to use super.paint, you are right! edited my comment!